# How to instantiate a Wrapper Class with more than 7 parameters in Criteria JPA API

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, jpa-2.1

I am in situation where i am suppose to select more that 10+ columns from the DB and on these selected fields i am applying logic in and getters. Therefore all these columns are parameters in  constructor of this wrapper class. I don't see any other way than to pass all these 10+ column values as parameters.

I am not using tuple in query here since . Then again i have to instantiate this wrapper objects using tuple in a for loop which is performance degradation and it will occupy more memory space also. Can any one suggest me work around to avoid this 10+ arguments in my constructor

```
criteriaBuilder.construct(MyWrapper.class,selections...)
```

and MyWrapper class has constructor like

```
public class MyWrapper{ 

public MyWrapper(String id,String name,String firstname,String lastname,Date lastvisited,Date lastModified, Date firstvisited,int numberofholidays,String currentproject,String lastproject,..)
@PostConstruct
public void doSomelogic(){



}
```

Comment: You can create a sort of `record` and pass it as a parameter